# Can't copy files to my target device in yocto

Tags: embedded, yocto, nvidia-jetson-nano, yocto-recipe

I am not being able to get my recipe to copy some files into my target device.

Currently the layers of my yocto project looks like this:

```
layer                 path                                      priority
==========================================================================
meta                  /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta  5
meta-tegra            /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-tegra  5
contrib               /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-tegra/contrib  4
meta-oe               /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-oe  6
meta-python           /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-python  7
meta-networking       /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-networking  5
meta-filesystems      /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-filesystems  6
meta-virtualization   /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-virtualization  8
meta-tegra-community  /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-tegra-community  20
meta-tegra-support    /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-tegra-support  40
meta-demo-ci          /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-demo-ci  40
meta-tegrademo        /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/layers/meta-tegrademo  50
workspace             /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/tegra-demo-distro/build/workspace  99
meta-mine            /home/juanpablo/work/yocto/meta-kwali     6
```

The meta-mine layer is the layer I created with a recipe to copy files inside the image I am then flashing to the sd card of a jetson-nano-devkit.

[image: meta-mine contents]

The recipe log-generators_0.1.bb has the following content:

```
DESCRIPTON = "A template recipe to copy files from host directory to target. \
               The example is written with docker-compose files"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://.env \
       file://docker-compose.yml \
      "

FILES_${PN} += "/test"

inherit allarch

do_install() {
  install -d ${D}/test
  install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/.env ${D}/test/
  install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/docker-compose.yml ${D}/test/
}
```

I have tried following the wiki's cookbook recipe and also 2 or 3 answers for similar questions posted in SO (e.g also defining ${S} = ${WORKDIR}, not using inherit allaarch, etc).

Any suggestions or help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your exact recipe on my setup and it seems to work correctly.

`bitbake log-generators` produces `log-generators{,-dbg,-dev}_0.1-r0_all.ipk` (I happen to use ipk) packages within `build/tmp/deploy/ipk/all/` directory.

While inspecting `log-generators_0.1-r0_all.ipk`, I can see the correct files in /test inside.

If you don't see the files in your target image, my best guess is that you need to reference the package in the image's install list. The simplest way is to add this to your `local.conf`:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " log-generators "
```

Comment: Thanks Yury. So I didn't call the command for the recipe, just for the image, i.e didn't call `bitbake log-generators` (and actually couldn't find the files inside build/tmp/work/all-oe4t-linux, not even a log-generators folder). Now trying the full workflow, I see that I also had to add FILES_{PN} for packaging.